# Firmware error from Sierra to Mojave

Tags: macos, ssd, error, mojave, firmware

I have a MacBook Pro 13-inch mid 2012 with macOS Sierra v. 10.12.6
Some technician installed Samsung SSD 840 EVO 1TB for me on this machine. There was no problem until I tried to install MacOS Mojave.

After some reboots on the installing process I have this error message:

> macOS could not be installed on your computer. An error occurred while
>   verifying firmware.

I already tried:

- A) Install on safe mode
- B) Format, reinstall Sierra, try A from there.
- C) Run First Aid from Recovery.

I don´t have the original HDD.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Some technician"?

Comment: Try running disk utility first aid from internet recovery

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. I'm updating the "Already tried" section, sorry.